# Iscsi disk not showing in lsblk- Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: iscsi

I logged in and I can find the sessions. But the disk is not showing in `lsblk` for Ubuntu 20.04.

I have done the same steps to Ubuntu 22.04 and I can see the disk using `lsblk`. is there any `iscsi` mode missing for Ubuntu 20.04. can someone suggest this.

```
 iscsiadm -m session
tcp: [3] 172.16.88.103:3260,1 iqn.2020-07.example.com:lun1 (non-flash)

 lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0   62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1611
loop1                       7:1    0 63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2182
loop2                       7:2    0 67.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22753
loop3                       7:3    0 91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
loop4                       7:4    0 39.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21184
sda                         8:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   98G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   49G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1  1.3G  0 rom
```